# How can I save temporary pictures with camera in Android?

Tags: android, camera

While trying to take a picture from the camera, and saving it on the cache folder of the app, I get no visible result. 
App doesn't crash, but on the LogCat I got this message once I try to set an ImageView src field to the URI of the file just taken:

> ```
> 09-17 14:03:32.200: I/System.out(5104): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
> 09-17 14:03:32.200: I/System.out(5104): buffer returned 
> 09-17 14:03:32.205: D/skia(5104): --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
> 09-17 14:03:32.205: I/System.out(5104): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: /data/data/com.example.me/cache/prefix1708798995.jpg
> ```

Code is quite simple, actually:

```
File tempFile;

try {
    tempFile = File.createTempFile("prefix", ".jpg");
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    AppUtil.showErrorToUser(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.ERROR_upload));
    return;
}

mCameraImage = tempFile.getAbsolutePath();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(tempFile);
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
```

And, in the `onActivityResult()`:

```
mIvAttach.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mBodyLocalUri));
```

I'm also **very** disappointed that I can't verify if pictures are actually taken, since I can't access `/data/data/myapp` folder (my GS3 is not rooted, and I still care about my warranty), therefore I'm not able to tell where the problem's very origin is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third-party camera apps have no rights to write to your internal storage, including `getCacheDir()` (which somehow `createTempFile()` is using, though it's not clear to me exactly how).

> I'm also very disappointed that I can't verify if pictures are actually taken, since I can't access /data/data/myapp folder (my GS3 is not rooted, and I still care about my warranty), therefore I'm not able to tell where the problem's very origin is.

First, you can, using `adb run-as`. Second, this is another manifestation of the same problem: just as DDMS cannot access internal storage, neither can the third-party app.

Use `getExternalCacheDir()` instead, to get a cache location on external storage, which a third-party camera app can try to write to. Note, though, that not all third-party camera apps will necessarily write to your requested location, due to bugs/limitations in those apps.

Comment: I added this to my code: `tempFile = File.createTempFile("kapp", ".jpg", getExternalCacheDir());`, but almost nothing has changed. This logcat is shown:
> Unable to create external cache directory
> Not a DRM File, opening notmally
> buffer returned 
> --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
> resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:/data/data/com...

Comment: @Gianluca: Make sure that you have the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.

Comment: Of course you were right. I was sure I did it, but in fact it was the wrong Manifest (the external library's one). Thank you very *very* much.

Comment: I think this statement is wrong `Third-party camera apps have no rights to write to your internal storage`, because they can access to internal Pictures folder and files with fileProvider

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov: In 2013, when this answer was written, roughly 0% of camera apps supported `content` schemes with `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`. Now, in 2017, it is higher than 0% but less than 100%.