# Is it possible with Codename One to take a temporary photo?

Tags: codenameone, delete-file, photo-gallery

Part of the process used in my app involves taking a photo (done with `Capture.capturePhoto()`). The photo is then resized to a small square of 200px and finally sent to a server.

I am able to delete the resized image with `FileSystemStorage.delete()` however the initial photo taken with `Capture.capturePhoto()` cannot be deleted because of the app being sand boxed (as described [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37952473/filesystemstorage-delete-doesnt-delete-captured-files-on-all-android-devices) )

This can be embarrassing for the user because these photos are polluting their gallery (the photos have no value for the user).

As deleting the initial photo is not possible, I was wondering if I could force the Captured photo to be stored in cache so that it gets automatically removed by the OS.

[Maybe this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18849570/how-can-i-save-temporary-pictures-with-camera-in-android) could be a solution for Android but I would prefer to avoid having to go native?

Consequently is it possible with Codename one to take a photo that will only be temporary and be deleted automatically ?

Thanks a lot,

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We try to delete the file automatically but since the OS takes the photo some platforms just stick it in the gallery and there isn't much we can do there. It's literally a matter of "this works on Android device A and fails on Android device B".

Apps like snapchat etc. don't use the device camera app but instead use the low level camera API's which are more complex and flaky. At this time we don't map these API's in Codename One so if you need something with lower level control you will need to use native interfaces. This is a non-trivial API though.

Comment: OK thanks Shai. It looks like I'll have to code my own camera with the low level camera api to take a temporary photo. Are you planning to map these API's in CN1 for the August's release ?